# How to HyperLink a value in Azure Data Studio?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hyperlink, azure-sql-database, azure-data-studio

I am using/exploring the below code to hyperlink a value in SQL Server. In SSMS, for both On-Premises DB and Azure SQL DB, it works fine.

When I run the same query through Azure Data Studio, not able to see the hyperlinked value in result set.

For ref, mentioned the tried query-

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp;
GO

CREATE TABLE #Temp (NORMAL_LINK VARCHAR(200),HYPERLINK XML);
GO
INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT 'https://arulmouzhi.wordpress.com/','https://arulmouzhi.wordpress.com/';
GO

SELECT 
NORMAL_LINK,
CAST(NORMAL_LINK AS XML) AS NORMAL_TO_HYPERLINK
FROM #Temp;
GO
```

Can anyone tell how to hyperlink a value and saw it in results in Azure Data Studio?

Attached pics for ref-

**SSMS**
[image: Hyperlinked Result set in SSMS]

**Azure Data Studio**
[image: No Hyperlinked Result set coming in Azure Data Studio]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hi Arulmouzhi, If my answer is helpful for you,  can you please mark it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that just the UI or display difference between SSMS and Azure Data Studio.

I also tried run the query in Azure Data Studio on my side:

1. SSMS query result showed us it as the normal hyperlink.
2. Azure Data Studio query result also is a hyperlink, but it looks more like a String. When we move the mouse to the `NORMAL_TO_HYPERLINK` result, we will see that the mouse changed the animation which show us it's a hyperlik. We can click it.

[image]

Hope this helps.